# Show only today's tasks in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-ql

I am using org-mode to organize my life. I got used to planning with **DEADLINE**. Additionally, I am using **Effort** property to predict how much effort that I have to show to finish all tasks.

**org-agenda-columns C-c C-x C-c** provide good interface to estimate effort in agenda. *org-agenda* shows today tasks, but it also shows future and overdue tasks at the same view like below in the picture. So, it makes really hard to understand how many hours that I have to spend today because it sums automatically all efforts.

[image: agenda-column-view]

I prepared small customized view to show just today tasks as I wanted, but these tasks are filtered with kind of regexp, so that reason, it's not possible to see next or previous days by using **org-agenda-earlier** and **org-agenda-later**

**TLDR;**

Is there any option to show only today's(not overdue and future) tasks in org-agenda?

**Things that can help**

Example input:

```
* Main
** Today 1st task
   DEADLINE: <2017-01-25 Wed>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EFFORT:   01:00
   :END:
**  Today 2nd task
   DEADLINE: <2017-01-25 Wed>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EFFORT:   00:30
   :END:
** Yesterday Overdue
   DEADLINE: <2017-01-24 Tue>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EFFORT:   02:00
   :END:
** Future task
   DEADLINE: <2017-01-30 Mon>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :EFFORT:   00:30
   :END:
```

**My non-interactive filter** that shows todays tasks

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("d" "daily"
         tags "DEADLINE>=\"<today>\"&DEADLINE<=\"<now>\""
         ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(todo-state-down)))
         (org-agenda-overriding-header "TODAY tasks"))))
```

Example **Interactive agenda-view** that shows just A priority

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
            '("f" agenda ""
              ((org-agenda-skip-function
                (lambda nil
                  (org-agenda-skip-entry-if (quote notregexp) "\\=.*\\[#A\\]")))
               (org-agenda-ndays 0)
               (org-agenda-overriding-header "Today's Priority #A tasks: "))))
```

Comment: There are probably a few ways to do this, but I like to set the `org-agenda-span` to `'day` and I set the `org-agenda-start-day` to a specific date.  See the doc-strings for each variable to see the available customizations.  I use `org-agenda-list` to create this particular type of agenda buffer.  As you probably know, there are three common functions -- the former mentioned, and `org-tags-view` and `org-search-view`.

Comment: See also the variable `org-deadline-warning-days`.  If you are doing anything with scheduled entries, you may also be interested in the variable `org-scheduled-past-days`.

Comment: I know `org-deadline-warning-days`. It can be solution to not showing future tasks but still there is not any solution in my mind about overdue tasks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**COMPATIBLE WITH ORG-MODE 9.0.3**

The function `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today` is designed to be used in conjunction with the `org-agenda-skip-function` and an `agenda` entry in the `org-agenda-custom-commands` that contains *proposed* entries such as:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("b" agenda "Today's Deadlines"
               ((org-agenda-span 'day)
                (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today))
                (org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline))
                (org-agenda-overriding-header "Today's Deadlines "))))
```

```lisp
(defun org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today ()
"If this function returns nil, the current match should not be skipped.
Otherwise, the function must return a position from where the search
should be continued."
  (ignore-errors
    (let ((subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t)))
          (deadline-day
            (time-to-days
              (org-time-string-to-time
                (org-entry-get nil "DEADLINE"))))
          (now (time-to-days (current-time))))
       (and deadline-day
            (not (= deadline-day now))
            subtree-end))))
```

---

**COMPATIBLE WITH ORG-MODE 8.2.10**

Emacs version 25.1 ships with `org-mode` version 8.2.10.  Within said release, there is an undocumented dynamically scoped variable called `org-agenda-only-exact-dates`, which can be used to accomplish the goal of the original poster.  Within the `org-agenda-custom-commands`, set `(org-agenda-only-exact-dates t)`.

`org-agenda-only-exact-dates` is used by `org-agenda-get-deadlines`, which is one of the functions responsible for the behavior the original poster wishes to customize.  It is also used by `org-agenda-get-scheduled`.  The function `org-timeline` is what sets this dynamically scoped variable to `t`.  This answer (above) takes advantage of said variable.

**CAVEAT**:  Many people are using the latest release of `org-mode` which does not ship with Emacs -- e.g., `org-mode` version 9.0.4.  I grepped 9.0.3 and did not see `org-agenda-only-exact-dates` used within either `org-agenda-get-deadlines` or `org-agenda-get-scheduled`.  I'm not sure why the `org-mode` team removed that variable or whether something else replaced its functionality in the latest release.  To the extent that another forum participant would like to research the code of 9.0.4 and post an alternative answer that works with the latest release, please feel free to do so.

Comment: Thanks again for interesting. I have just seen that commit also I'll analyze later it. 
I am using 9.0.4 so as you say as you remark  `(org-agenda-only-exact-dates t)` doesn't work with `org-agenda-custom-commands`

Comment: @itirazimvar -- when you have time, please test the alternative solution that utilizes `org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-not-today` and let me know if that works with `org-mode` version 9.0.4.  I don't have that version installed on my computer, but I would imagine that it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now It works with your skip method as I want. Few days ago I reverted `org-mode` to *9.0.3*. Promise while I am free I'll test and write there how 9.0.4 will react. Even I don't have doubt :) Regards.

Comment: Now I realized that there is mistake because of `current-time` variable. The problem is about to see yesterday and tomorrow task when I press `f` and `b`. So If you know how to get preferred day of agenda please change if not I can try.
Regards.

Comment: I see the issue with moving forwards and backwards in time.  I would suggest launching a new question that references this thread.

Comment: In my opinion it's not necessary new question I'll search later and I'll update when I have done. Thanks in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 4):

I am answering my question that I asked long time ago.

A new package which name [orq-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql) is also lead us to desired situation.

Additionally provides many like filtering, ordering etc on-the-fly.

You can use code block at below, also interactive `M-x org-ql-view` allow us some default filtering methods.

```
(org-ql-view "Today")
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, is org-ql-view "view" only? or is it editable view?