# Searching for org-tags programmatically (without regexp)?

Tags: org-mode

The function `org-tags-view` allows you to build up semi-complex searches for tags using regexp:

```
(org-tags-view t "+PROP1={value}&+PROP2={[1-2]}")
```

However, regexp is very limited. Is there a way to search using some sort of matcher function that can, i.e., inspect an org header's properties, do some computations on them, and returns `t` or `nil` depending upon whether the computation matches in the way I specify?

Comment: If you have already read the advanced searching page of the `org-mode` manual -- https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html -- and if you did not find what you are looking for, then it may behoove you to create a minimal working example with a few headers with drawers (if applicable) and ask how to comb through all of the `org-mode` flat files defined by `org-agenda-files` (testing for a specified criteria) and someone can write-up a solution.

Comment: The `org-agenda-skip-function` is a custom function written to suit the needs of a user ... Here is a link to an example I wrote up a couple of years ago that looks for a date ... https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30194/2287

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `org-search-view` that adds the value of A and B and returns `t` when the sum of both numbers is equal to `N`. The regular expression at the end combines metadata and full text query, as explained [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html), but if you really want to avoid false positives you may have to use something more unique (like IDs, see `(find-library "org-id.el")`).

```
* Five
  :PROPERTIES:
  :A: 3
  :B: 2
  :END:

* Four
  :PROPERTIES:
  :A: 2
  :B: 2
  :END:
```

```el
(defun n-equals-a-plus-b-p (n)
  (interactive "nNumber: ")
  (let (entries)
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (let* ((el (org-element-at-point))
              (a (org-element-property :A el))
              (b (org-element-property :B el)))
         (when (and a b (= (+ (string-to-number a)
                              (string-to-number b))
                           n))
           (push (org-element-property :title el) entries))))
     nil 'agenda)
    (unless (null entries)
      (org-search-view nil (concat "+{^\\*\s\\("
                                   (mapconcat #'identity entries "\\|")
                                   "\\)} +{:\\(A\\|B\\):.}")))))
```