# Do not show deadline if scheduled

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, deadline

Here is a sample entry:

```
*** TODO Some Task
SCHEDULED: <2021-07-19 Mon> DEADLINE: <2021-07-01 Thu +1y>
```

As you can see, it is past deadline. But it is still incomplete and it is scheduled for a future date.

I want such tasks to show in the agenda only on or after the scheduled date, not before.

How do I achieve that?

As a side note, if I set the variable `org-agenda-todo-ignore-deadlines` to `'past`, the global TODO list does not show this item. But the agenda does! Is there a way to force similar behavior for the agenda?

Comment: `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled` does *almost* what you want, I think (it will still show it on the deadline date itself). I don't know of a built-in way to do it exactly the way you want. Check out the `pre-scheduled` value in particular.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. But setting that variable does not seem to help. It seems to be about what to do with the *pre* -warning. If the deadline is in the future, setting that variable works. But like in my case, when the deadline was in the past, it does not work. Would you mind putting my snippet in your org agenda file and see if it works?

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @NickD What I mean is with `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled` set to `t`, if the deadline is in the past, it will keep showing in the agenda whether it is scheduled for a future date or not. But I want to suppress deadline entry in agenda if it is scheduled even if the deadline was in the past and scheduled is in the future. Any way to get that behavior?

Comment: I don't know of a way to get that behavior (other than changing the code of course). That's why I added a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Perhaps the O.P. can craft something together using a custom skip function -- here is something I wrote up a long time ago, which is not a direct answer, but may be a head-start:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30194/2287

Comment: @NickD @lawlist I have edited the question to include some more data. There is a variable `org-agenda-todo-ignore-deadlines`. It does what I want, but for the global TODO list. Any way I can force the agenda to do what the TODO list is doing?